# Nosetests ran 0 tests

Tags: python, nosetests

When I run

`nosetests --doctest-extension=.txt`

I get

> Ran 0 tests in 0.002s
>
> OK

Why does it say 0 tests when I have tests in the file README.txt?

Comment: What does ```nosetests --verbose``` shows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `doctest` you also have to specify that `nose` has to run with the doctest plugin enabled.

This should do the trick:

```
nosetests --with-doctest --doctest-extension=txt
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I read this in a book a few years old and probably the commands have changed.